# Calling an ImageJ/FIJI macro from inside a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, imagej, imagej-macro, pyimagej

I would like to use ImageJ and some of its macros and call them from inside a jupyter notebook. I am aware of [PyimageJ](https://github.com/imagej/pyimagej), and I have been able to install it and load an image for display using ImageJ methods. But I am having some difficulties in getting the grasp of how to call and run the java-based plugins that come with imageJ nor load user-written macros.

I have been looking at this example: https://omero-guides.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiji/docs/imagej_python.html

The example in question is actually for [Omero](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/omero/), which I do not require nor have access to (registration for Omero is required).

I think I lack a more transversal understanding of working across different platforms, Could anyone please give me a hand?

Many thanks in advance.